# Complex number $\frac{z}{z+1}=2+3i$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Given that $\frac{z}{z+1}=2+3i$, find the complex number $z$, giving your answer in the form of $x+yi$.

Can someone give me some hints for solving this question? Thanks

Comment: exactly as you would solve any other equation with "$x$".. Multiply by $z + 1$ both members and find $z$

Comment: Do you know how to solve $\frac{x}{x+1}=2$? It is the same way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can flip the left hand side so that you have $$\frac{z+1}{z} = 1 + \frac1z = \frac1{2+3i}$$  gives $$\frac1z = \frac1{2+3i} - 1=\frac{-1-3i}{2+3i}= \frac{(-1-3i)(-1+3i)}{(2+3i)(-1+3i)}=\frac{10}{-11++3i}$$

therfore, $$z = -\frac{11}{10} + \frac3{10} i  $$

Answer (score 1):

Hint :

$$\frac{z}{z+1}=\frac{z+1-1}{z+1}=1-\frac{1}{z+1}=2+3i \implies -1-3i=\frac{1}{z+1}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{z}{z+1}=2+3i\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\left(\frac{z}{z+1}\right)(z+1)=(2+3i)(z+1)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{z(z+1)}{z+1}=(2+3i)z+(2+3i)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z=(2+3i)z+(2+3i)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z-(2+3i)=((2+3i)z+(2+3i))-(2+3i)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$(-1-3i)z=2+3i\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{(-1-3i)}{-1-3i}z=\frac{2+3i}{-1-3i}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z=-\frac{11}{10}+\frac{3}{10}i$$